# Windows Authentication IIS7 Virtual Application

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to setup a website with a virtual application that uses windows authentication in iis7. The strange thing is that when I create a new website that points directly to the bin directory, the windows authentication works correctly. When the app is put as a virtual application under the root, the windows authentication fails (in that it constantly prompts for credentials before throwing a 401).

I have windows authentication turned on for the virtual application as well as the root website.

In IIS7 (as independent website, working):

site:port

In IIS7 (as virtual app, not working):

site:port/WebAppA

Root, WebAppA (Virtual Application)

In web.config:

```
<location path="controllers">
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="INTRANET\Domain Users" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="index.html">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="INTRANET\Domain Users" />
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
 </location>
<system.web>
```

Not sure why it would work correctly in one configuration, but not as a virtual app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by virtual application ... IIS has "Virtual Directory" and "Application" but nothing like virtual application.

When you include a virtual directory such as root\webapp1 ... try converting it into an application ... right click -> convert to application and see if that works.